# Can an electron flow without potential difference?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, potential, electrical-resistance, voltage

Have seen that a positive charge flows from higher potential to lower potential,

the direction of this flow is opposite to the flow of electrons,

my concern is if an electron is thrown, it moves and there is no potential difference (p.d),

the same thing probably happens inside a conductor where electrons move by heat inside the conductor,

so is it necessary that movement of electrons need a p.d or they can move without p.d also?

Answer (score 1):

> Can an electron flow without potential difference?

Yes. But only if the medium where the flow occurs has zero resistance (e.g. is a vacuum or a superconductor).

> so is it necessary that movement of electrons need a p.d or they can
> move without p.d also?

Let's start by defining what we mean by "movement". There is the random movement of electrons associated with thermal effects (heat as you mentioned). This involves no potential difference. Then there is the collective movement of electrons, referred to as drift current, which is superimposed on the random movement of electrons.

When the collective movement of electrons occurs in the presence of electrical resistance between two points, a potential difference is required between the two points to maintain that movement overcoming the loss of kinetic energy due to collisions. The potential difference $V$ between two points is the work per unit charge required to move that charge between the two points.

If there were zero resistance between two points, no work would be required for the collective movement of the electrons, i.e., the potential difference would be zero.  The thing is all conductors, with the exception of superconductors, have some resistance. If there were zero resistance, then the only work required to move the electrons is that by an electric field to overcome their inertia to start them moving. Once in motion, they could theoretically continue to move forever at constant speed.

A mechanical analogy is an object (analogous to the electron) initially at rest sliding on a frictionless surface (analogous to a zero resistance conductor). An initial force is needed to accelerate the object (overcome its inertia), but after that it will theoretically slide forever at constant speed. If the surface was not frictionless, analogous to non zero electrical resistance, then work would be required to keep the object sliding at constant speed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Bod D,thanks for ur answer,l request if u can reach one of other queries what has been closed now at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/717025/how-do-we-calculate-the-electric-potential-difference-between-the-plates-of-a-ba

Comment: I was one of the ones who voted to close it because I, and the others who voted to close it, didn't understand the question.

Comment: ok,will try to edit it,at times my questions are not well understood because of my Indian english,thanks.

Comment: @sachin No worries. I'm sure your Indian English is better than my English Indian, which is non existent!

Answer (score 0):

Of course they can. Electrons have inertia, so an electron entering a region of space free of electromagnetic fields will coast through in accordance with Newton's first law.

In practice, this works in a vacuum. Normal conductors have resistance, so a bit of potential difference is required to move electrons against this friction.

Answer (score 0):

What your describing is a convection current.

You have conduction currents when you apply a potential and the conduction current is $J = \sigma E$ where $\sigma$ is the conductivity of the material and E is the electric field. But you can also have convection currents when charges are carried mechanically, for example charged dust or smoke particles being carried by the wind.

Answer (score 0):

Electrons can move from point A to point B without potential difference.

In ordinary circuit with resistance, current is proportional to net electromotive force. This electromotive force does not need presence of potential difference. For example, emf can be due to induced electric field, due to changing magnetic field, or due to motional emf due to conductor moving in magnetic field.

In superconductors, DC current can flow even without any electromotive force, just due to inertia.